# How to replicate the "Move to Dropbox" Mac OS X Finder context menu item for other apps?

Tags: macos, mac, dropbox, context-menu, textmate

When Dropbox is installed on Mac OS X, it installs a "Move to Dropbox" context menu item:

[image: Move to Dropbox context menu item]

I would like to install a similar menu item for other apps and actions. Specifically, I would like an **"Open in AppName"** menu item that allows me to quickly open files in my favorite text editor  or image editor without wading through the "Open With..." menu mess.

- Open in TextMate
- Open in Pixelmator
- Open in etc.

I have found ways to [add](http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/customize-mac-right-click-menu/) Automator [services](http://justaddwater.dk/2009/12/08/how-to-add-open-folder-in-textmate-to-finder-context-menu/) for these actions.

However, these are installed at the bottom of the menu, in "Services". They also **do not have an app icon**, which is key for quickly visually finding the correct menu item in the list.

[image: Open in TextMate menu item service via automator]

I would instead like to exactly replicate the "Move to Dropbox" menu item:

- App Icon is displayed.
- Near top of context menu, not at the very bottom.

What method does Dropbox use? How can I replicate it for any given app or action?

Comment: I don't know the exact answer to your question, but I believe you have to register your app as a Contextual Menu handler.  There are other utilities (like Folder Glance and Finderpop) which make some nice modifications to the CM menu, so you might try asking them about it.  As a workaround that's nicer than an iconless Services-menu entry, why not use the built-in "Open With" menu.  *If* the app is registered to handle a filetype (like Text or JPG), it should show up in the Open With menu (with an icon!).

Comment: Yes, "Open With" works for many common file types. But I often find myself opening rare/custom file extensions in TextMate. Today it was a `.keylayout` file. "Open With" does not know these are text files, and thus TextMate isn't in the menu. I don't want to register each and every random filetype individually; I'd like my text editor to be a default option for *all* files.

Comment: You can edit the Info.plist file inside the app to "register" it to handle more file types/extensions.  I've never had luck getting an app to register itself to handle ALL types/extensions, but it definitely works if you add each extension.  This is a pain, because it take a little Googling and experimenting to get right, and you also have to save that Info.plist to merge your edits back into the app anytime the app gets updated. A much simpler way is to just add your app to the Finder's toolbar (the toolbar at the top of each Finder window, not the Sidebar), then drag any file to your app!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can now use a [Finder Sync Extension](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/Finder.html) to add items to the Finder Context Menu in OS X 10.10 Yosemite:

[image: Finder Sync Extension in Context Menu]